# How to run powershell script from batch file while the ps script path has spaces and path is derived from %~dp0%

Tags: powershell, batch-file

I have a batch file Install.bat which calls the GetVersion.ps1 powershell script. These two scripts are in the same folder (C:\Install_Media) and i am calling the powershell script by getting the directory where the batch file is(using %~dp0%).

The following code works good if there is no space in the path where these files are located. If there is a space in the path then shellscript is not getting executed (eg C:\Install Media). The script stops saying that The term 'C:\Install' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script..

```
@ECHO OFF
set SRC_DIR=%~dp0%
Powershell set-executionPolicy remotesigned
Powershell %SRC_DIR%\GetSLMClientVersion.ps1
Powershell set-executionPolicy restricted
```

[Error ScreenShot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5YRNB.jpg)

Comment: Use quotes.  `powershell -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File "%~dp0GetSLMClientVersion.ps1"`

Comment: You might find [SS64 on Variable Expansion](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-args.html) to be of interest - specifically, you may want to change `%~dp0%` to `%~dsp0%`.

Comment: @ TheIncorrigible1, thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Parameter expansion uses just a single `%` character at the beginning of the expression. Also, you don't need to change the execution policy back and forth. `powershell.exe` has a parameter for temporarily overriding the execution policy. And spaces in the path are best handled by putting the path in quotes, as [TheIncorrigible1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52880803/how-to-run-powershell-script-from-batch-file-while-the-ps-script-path-has-spaces/52880950#comment92675287_52880803) pointed out in the comments.

Change your code to this:

```
@echo off
powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File "%~dp0\GetSLMClientVersion.ps1"
```

Comment: The querent's problem is not related to the parameter expansion, which does in fact work when used with `%...%` (as this is maintained for compatibility with earlier versions of CMD and COMMAND). The problem is that the expansion results in a filename with spaces, and the PowerShell command line when used within a batch file does not always handle quotes as expected. To avoid such issues, it's better to avoid pathnames that have spaces; using `~dsp` instead of `~dp` accomplishes this.

Comment: @JeffZeitlin My answer addresses all issues that I perceived with the OP's original code. Even if `%~0%` does work I don't see a good reason for sticking to legacy syntax. As for avoiding spaces in paths: I would disagree on that. Putting a simple path like the OP has in quotes takes care of spaces just fine.