# Batch-Hell with empty space in filepath

Tags: batch-file

currently I am in the batch-hell. I want to call my powershell script via a batch file. This works properly as long as there are no empty spaces in the path. For example this is working

```
          set DATAPATH="%~1"
    set XMLFILE="%~2"
    set PSFILE="C:\dev\workflow\handler.ps1"
    echo %PSFILE%
    echo powershell -command %PSFILE% -datapath """%DATAPATH%""" -xmlFile """%XMLFILE%"""
    powershell -command %PSFILE% -datapath """%DATAPATH%""" -xmlFile """%XMLFILE%"""
    IF %ERRORLEVEL% == 0 (echo true) else (echo false)
```

When I change it to use a path which contains a space in the file path it is not working.

```
    set DATAPATH="%~1"
    set XMLFILE="%~2"
    set PSFILE="C:\dev\work flow\handler.ps1"
    echo %PSFILE%
    echo powershell -command %PSFILE% -datapath """%DATAPATH%""" -xmlFile """%XMLFILE%"""
    powershell -command %PSFILE% -datapath """%DATAPATH%""" -xmlFile """%XMLFILE%"""
    IF %ERRORLEVEL% == 0 (echo true) else (echo false)
```

The error message "C:\dev\work" was not not found as a name of a cmdlet indicates for me that the space is the root of the problem. Any idea I tried it also to define the variable PSFILE like this

```
set PSFILE="""C:\dev\work flow\handler.ps1"""
```

Maybe someone knows a solution and shows me how to handle spaces in a batch file path.

[image]

Comment: `set "PSFILE=C:\dev\work flow\handler.ps1"`  Notice where my quotes are, and then use it as `.. `"%PSFILE%"` with quotes.

Comment: Once you've set your variables correctly in your [tag:batch-file], the command to execute should be, `PowerShell -File "%PSFILE%" -datapath "%DATAPATH%" -xmlFile "%XMLFILE%"`, _(you should not be using command to execute a script file)_. Obviously this assumes that you have appropriately set the `param` strings `$datapath` and `xmlFile` inside your `.ps1` file, and have a permissable execution policy too. The powershell script is however outside of the scope of this question, so I would suggest for that, you create a new question.

Comment: I changed my answer, you should try the quotes AND changing `-command` to `-File`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

cmd sees whitespace as the the separator between commands and paramters. So you need:

```
    set "DATAPATH=%~1"
    set "XMLFILE=%~2"
    set "PSFILE=C:\dev\work flow\handler.ps1"
    echo "%PSFILE%"
    echo powershell -file "%PSFILE%" -datapath "%DATAPATH%" -xmlFile "%XMLFILE%"
    powershell -file "%PSFILE%" -datapath "%DATAPATH%" -xmlFile "%XMLFILE%"
    IF %ERRORLEVEL% equ 0 (echo true) else (echo false)
```

Note the double quotes starts before the variable and end at the end of the variable.

Also note `equ` used instead of `==` in the `if` statement.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the extended *SET-syntax*, `set "DATAPATH=%~1"` the quotes are BEFORE the variable name and at the end of the content.
This will set the content **without** quotes to the variable and avoids trailing invisble white spaces.

The you can use the variables with surrounded quotes.

```
powershell -File "%PSFILE%" -datapath "%DATAPATH%" -xmlFile "%XMLFILE%"
```

`-File` instead of `-command` seems to work, see also [How to run powershell script from batch file while the ps script path has spaces and path is derived from %~dp0](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52880950/463115)